# SQL Server 2008 - MAX() - function produces invalid/unexpected output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, max

Consider following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT FunctionNbr,FunctionDesc, MAX(date_altered)
FROM Persontable
WHERE FunctionNbr IN ('00000001','00000002','00000003')
AND LEN(RTRIM(FunctionDesc)) > 0 
GROUP BY FunctionNbr,FunctionDesc
```

the persontable contains all the employees with their respective function. the date_altered may vary depending on changes made on SAP.

My expected output would be that i get a record for every employee with one of those functionNbr and with the same date_altered.

example of expected output:

```
FunctionNbr | FunctionDesc | date_altered
--------------------------------------------
00000001    | Function A   | 2014-01-01    (=row from employee 001 with functionNbr = 0000001 and date_altered = 2013-12-20)
00000001    | Function A   | 2014-01-01    (=row from employee 002 with functionNbr = 0000001 and date_altered = 2013-12-24)
00000001    | Function A   | 2014-01-01    (=row from employee 003 with functionNbr = 0000001 and date_altered = 2014-01-01)
00000002    | Function B   | 2013-12-13    (=row from employee 004 with functionNbr = 0000002 and date_altered = 2013-12-13)
00000002    | Function B   | 2013-12-13    (=row from employee 005 with functionNbr = 0000002 and date_altered = 2013-12-11)
```

yet my output looks as follows:

```
FunctionNbr | FunctionDesc | date_altered
--------------------------------------------
00000001    | Function A   | 2013-12-20    (=row from employee 001 with functionNbr = 0000001 and date_altered = 2013-12-20)
00000001    | Function A   | 2013-12-24    (=row from employee 002 with functionNbr = 0000001 and date_altered = 2013-12-24)
00000001    | Function A   | 2014-01-01    (=row from employee 003 with functionNbr = 0000001 and date_altered = 2014-01-01)
00000002    | Function B   | 2013-12-13    (=row from employee 004 with functionNbr = 0000002 and date_altered = 2013-12-13)
00000002    | Function B   | 2013-12-11    (=row from employee 005 with functionNbr = 0000002 and date_altered = 2013-12-11)
```

**Question:** In this case, Why doensn't the MAX() function always take the last date_altered

**Note:** For every employee there is only 1 row

Comment: How can your function return `FunctionNbr` with value `00000001` anyway? It's not in your `IN` clause... Please provide consistent information in your question!

Comment: You shouldn't be using `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same `SELECT` clause.  They do the same/similar things and you're giving them conflicting parameters.  I am pretty sure that it's undefined what happens to SQL in this case.

Comment: @Dittmar mistake of mine. Tried to do it with easy example but forgot to change the query. Will do so directly.@RBarryYoung removed the distinct to test your statement but the output still remains the same.

Comment: try: `SELECT DISTINCT FunctionNbr,FunctionDesc, MAX(CAST(date_altered AS DATE))` it is possible that the dates are stored as text

Comment: @MarkD You're right! the dates were stored as text. The daily update apparently added a random amount trailing spaces. example '2013-12-20    '. How stupid of me to look past the most obvious thing....  Can you post your answer so i can approve it?

Comment: @RBarryYoung It's not undefined. The `DISTINCT` is redundant though in this case and should be removed.

Comment: @ypercube Where is it defined?

Comment: @RBarryYoung You said *"I am pretty sure that it's undefined what happens to SQL in this case"*. The query is valid SQL and the output is well defined (although 100% identical with if you remove the `DISTINCT`), that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @ypercube The `DISTINCT` has a different set of parameters than the `GROUP BY`.  Where is it defined how the conflict between DISTINCT and GROUP BY is resolved?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Join: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46163/discussing-dinstinct-group-by

Comment: @ypercube Ah, I see, its the clause/operator precedence order that resolves it.  Never mind that then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very possible that the table's dates are stored as text. Try this;

```
SELECT FunctionNbr,FunctionDesc, MAX(CAST(date_altered AS DATETIME)
FROM Persontable
WHERE FunctionNbr IN ('00000001','00000002','00000003')
AND LEN(RTRIM(FunctionDesc)) > 0 
GROUP BY FunctionNbr,FunctionDesc
```

I've removed the `DISTINCT` as correctly suggested by RBarryYoung